# Customize my custom taxonomy table in Admin panel

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, admin, css

I've registered a new taxonomy for my custom post type, and now I'm trying to edit the taxonomy table.

I've successfully removed the description column but I can't figure it out **how to edit column width for the column that shows the number of custom post types found** in that particular taxonomy. The column's CSS class seems to be `column-posts`, and thus, its width is set to `10%`.

**Shouldn't the column's CSS class be `column-{my-custom-post-type}` and not the default?**

**Can I somehow force the column's width be set to `auto` or set its class to match my custom-post-type?**

Here's what I've done so far:

**Custom Post Type**

```
function registerPersonnelPostType() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => __( 'Personnel', 'xxx' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'Personnel', 'xxx' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'xxx' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Personnel Member', 'xxx' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Personnel Member', 'xxx' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Personnel Member', 'xxx' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Personnel Member', 'xxx' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Personnel', 'xxx' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No personnel found', 'xxx' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No personnel found in Trash', 'xxx' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Personnel:', 'xxx' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Personnel', 'xxx' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'description'           => 'Staff names and descriptions',
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 20,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'rewrite'               => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'personnel', $args );
}
```

**Taxonomy**

```
function departmentInit() {
    $labels = array(        
        'name'                  => __( 'Department', 'xxx' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'Department', 'xxx' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Departments', 'xxx' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Departments', 'xxx' ),
        'parent_item'           => __( 'Parent Department', 'xxx' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Department:', 'xxx' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Department', 'xxx' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Department', 'xxx' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Department', 'xxx' ),
        'new_item_name'         => __( 'New Department Name', 'xxx' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Department', 'xxx' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'department' )
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'department' , array('personnel'), $args );
}
```

**Hooks for editing columns**

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-department_columns', 'departmentColumns' );

function departmentColumns( $columns ) {    
    if ( isset( $columns[ 'description' ] ) ) {
        unset( $columns[ 'description' ] );
    }

    return $columns;        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'cor_admin_print_styles', 200 );
function cor_admin_print_styles() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( 'edit-tags' === $screen->base && 'department' === $screen->taxonomy ) {
        echo <<<EOF
<style>
    .fixed .column-posts {
        width: auto;
    }
    .widefat .num, .column-comments, .column-links, .column-posts {
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
EOF;
    }
}
```

Comment: Magnificent! That really did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Although I still don't get it why the column won't have a class name `column-personnel`

Comment: Thanks for the followup :) I know on different occasions a new `<body>` class will automatically be added. Also, if you really need to change a lot of CSS, you could always add one yourself. http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2013/02/wordpress-admin-body-class.html

Comment: As a side-note @kaiser (and stephenharris) recently made a great [plugin](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info) which displays most info about the current admin screen globals, contextual hooks, etc. (terribly sorry about the double comment/links, but I do think __all__ are quite relevant to the original question)

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in functions.php file to achieve this :

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>
   #posts.column-posts{width:auto;}
} 
</style>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, this is partly the solution – that would also change all other tables, eg. `categories` which is I want to prevent.